# Prove $ \frac{4cos^{2}(2x)-4cos^2(x)+3sin^2(x)}{4cos^2(\frac{5\pi}{2} - x) -sin^22(x-\pi)} = \frac{8cos(2x)+1}{2(cos(2x)-1)}$

Tags: trigonometry

> > Question: Prove
> >
> > $$ \frac{4cos^{2}(2x)-4cos^2(x)+3sin^2(x)}{4cos^2(\frac{5\pi}{2} - x) -sin^22(x-\pi)} = \frac{8cos(2x)+1}{2(cos(2x)-1)}$$

My attempt starting with the bottom line on the LHS

$$ {4cos^2(\frac{5\pi}{2} - x) -sin^22(x-\pi)} $$

$$ sin(x) = (\frac{\pi}{2} - x)  $$

$$ 4sin^2(x) - sin^2(2x-2\pi)$$

$$  4sin^2(x) - sin^2(2x)cos^2(2\pi) + cos^2(2x)sin^2(2\pi)$$

$$ 4sin^2(x) - sin^2(2x) $$

$$ 4( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}cos(2x)) - (1-cos^2(2x)) $$

$$ 2 - 2cos(2x) - 1 + cos^2(2x) $$

$$  cos^2(2x) - 2cos(2x) + 1 $$

$$ (cos(2x) - 1)(cos(2x) - 1) $$

So I think I have simplified it as much as possible here

Now the top line

$$ {4cos^{2}(2x)-4cos^2(x)+3sin^2(x)} $$

$$ 4cos^2(2x) - 4cos^2(x) + 3(1-cos^2(x))$$

$$ 4cos^2(2x) - 4cos^2(x) + 3-3cos^2(x) $$

$$ 4cos^2(2x) - 7 cos^2(x) + 3 $$

Now I am stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the numerator,
$$ 4\cos^2(2x) - 7 \cos^2(x) + 3 $$
As suggested in the comments, use,
$$\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$$
Thus
$$ 4\cos^2(2x) - 7 \cos^2(x) + 3= 4\cos^2(2x)-\frac72-\frac72\cos(2x)+3=\frac12(8\cos^2(2x)-7\cos(2x)-1)=\frac12(8\cos(2x)+1)(\cos(2x)-1)$$

Dividing this with the expression for the denominator you have got gives the desired result.